# Why is the input value the same for different components?

Tags: reactjs

I want to have unique input values for distinct input fields on a login/registration form. Currently, whenever I type into the input fields on the login form, the same values appear in the register form in the corresponding fields (username and password). I have tried moving the inputs via CSS so they are not aligned exactly on each form, but that did not help. Below is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [ showRegisterForm, setShowRegisterForm ] = useState(false);

  function handleOnClick() {
    setShowRegisterForm(!showRegisterForm);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>Toggle Register Form</button>
      <LoginForm showRegisterForm={showRegisterForm} />
    </div>
  )
}

function LoginForm(props) {
  const showRegisterForm = props.showRegisterForm;

  if(showRegisterForm === false) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <label htmlFor="login-username">Username</label>
        <input id="login-username" type="text" />
        <label htmlFor="login-password">Password</label>
        <input id="login-password" type="password" />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <label htmlFor="register-username">Username</label>
        <input id="register-username" type="text" />
        <label htmlFor="register-password">Password</label>
        <input id="register-password" type="password" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a react sandbox on what you are trying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy fix is to give one of the top-level `<div>`s returned by `LoginForm` a key so that [during React's reconciliation process](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), the divs are interpreted to be entirely distinct (rather than React simply tweaking the existing DOM nodes to match the new props being passed down).

```js
function App() {
  const [ showRegisterForm, setShowRegisterForm ] = React.useState(false);

  function handleOnClick() {
    setShowRegisterForm(!showRegisterForm);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>Toggle Register Form</button>
      <LoginForm showRegisterForm={showRegisterForm} />
    </div>
  )
}

function LoginForm(props) {
  const showRegisterForm = props.showRegisterForm;

  if(showRegisterForm === false) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <label htmlFor="login-username">Username</label>
        <input id="login-username" type="text" />
        <label htmlFor="login-password">Password</label>
        <input id="login-password" type="password" />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div key="register">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <label htmlFor="register-username">Username</label>
        <input id="register-username" type="text" />
        <label htmlFor="register-password">Password</label>
        <input id="register-password" type="password" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

The better fix would be to use controlled components instead - add state for the login username, login password, register username, and register password. React generally works best with controlled components anyway.

```js
const { useState } = React;
function App() {
  const [ showRegisterForm, setShowRegisterForm ] = React.useState(false);

  function handleOnClick() {
    setShowRegisterForm(!showRegisterForm);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>Toggle Register Form</button>
      <LoginForm showRegisterForm={showRegisterForm} />
    </div>
  )
}

function LoginForm(props) {
  const showRegisterForm = props.showRegisterForm;
  const [loginUsername, setLoginUsername] = useState('');
  const [loginPassword, setLoginPassword] = useState('');
  const [registerUsername, setRegisterUsername] = useState('');
  const [registerPassword, setRegisterPassword] = useState('');
  
  if(showRegisterForm === false) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <label htmlFor="login-username">Username</label>
        <input id="login-username" value={loginUsername} onChange={(e) => { setLoginUsername(e.target.value); }} />
        <label htmlFor="login-password">Password</label>
        <input id="login-password" type="password" value={loginPassword} onChange={(e) => { setLoginPassword(e.target.value); }} />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div key="register">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <label htmlFor="register-username">Username</label>
        <input id="register-username" type="text" value={registerUsername} onChange={(e) => { setRegisterUsername(e.target.value); }} />
        <label htmlFor="register-password">Password</label>
        <input id="register-password" type="password"  value={registerPassword} onChange={(e) => { setRegisterPassword(e.target.value); }}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```